# Select which plot to display in a shiny app based on user choice

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app which generates 2 plots and one table. As you will see I want to select which one of them will be displayed every time based on the `radiobuttons()` input. Until now I get an error `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` Which object exactly is of type closure? Note that the first is a ggplot object the second  is a plotly object and the third a datatable.

```
    # ui.R
        library(shiny)
        library(plotly)
        pageWithSidebar(
          headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
          sidebarPanel(
            uiOutput("filter_degree")

          ),
          mainPanel(
            uiOutput('plot')

          )
        )
        #server.r
        function(input, output, session) {
          output$filter_degree<-renderUI({
            radioButtons("rd","Select Option",choices = c("Mileage","Regression",'Table'),
                         selected = "Mileage")
          })


          output$plot <- renderUI({
           if(input$rd=="Mileage"){
             output$plot1<-renderUI({
            # Boxplots of mpg by number of gears 
            # observations (points) are overlayed and jittered
            qplot(gear, mpg, data=mtcars, geom=c("boxplot", "jitter"), 
                  fill=gear, main="Mileage by Gear Number",
                  xlab="", ylab="Miles per Gallon")
             })
            }


            else if(input$rd=="Regression"){
              output$plot2<-renderUI({
            x <- c(1:100)
            random_y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
            data <- data.frame(x, random_y)

            p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~random_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
              })
            }


            else if(input$rd=="Table"){

              output$tbl =  DT::renderDataTable(datatable(
                iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE,scrollY = T, scroller = TRUE, scrollX = T),selection = list(target="cell",mode="single"),rownames = F)
              )
            }

          })

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the plot/table output as part of the if/then sequence (`plotOutput("plot1")`, etc.).  Otherwise, it has nothing to render.  Also, there appears to be an error in the ploty call, but I haven't fixed it for you.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("filter_degree")

  ),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput('plot')

  )
)
#server.r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$filter_degree<-renderUI({
    radioButtons("rd","Select Option",choices = c("Mileage","Regression",'Table'),
                 selected = "Mileage")
  })


  output$plot <- renderUI({
    if(input$rd=="Mileage"){
      output$plot1<-renderPlot({
        # Boxplots of mpg by number of gears 
        # observations (points) are overlayed and jittered
        qplot(gear, mpg, data=mtcars, geom=c("boxplot", "jitter"), 
              fill=gear, main="Mileage by Gear Number",
              xlab="", ylab="Miles per Gallon")
      })
      plotOutput("plot1")
    }


    else if(input$rd=="Regression"){
      output$plot2<-renderUI({
        x <- c(1:100)
        random_y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
        data <- data.frame(x, random_y)

        p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~random_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
      })
      plotlyOutput("plot2")
    }


    else if(input$rd=="Table"){

      output$tbl =  DT::renderDataTable(datatable(
        iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE,scrollY = T, scroller = TRUE, scrollX = T),selection = list(target="cell",mode="single"),rownames = F)
      )

      dataTableOutput("tbl")
    }

  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Never mind cause it was just to show that the 2nd plot was a plorly. Tnx for your time and answer!